# Requiring exported CMake targets within the exporting build tree

Tags: cmake, build-system

I have a CMake Project `Foobar` that contains a subdirectory `examples` that can also be used as a stand-alone CMake build. To do that this sub-directory performs a `find_package(Foobar)` and uses the exported targets. `Foobar` provides a `FoobarConfig.cmake`, `FoobarConfigVersion.cmake`, and a `FoobarExports.cmake` and can be used without a FindModule.

The code roughly looks like this:

```
### Top-Level CMakeLists.txt ###
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(Foobar)

add_library(X SHARED ${my_sources})
install(TARGETS X EXPORT FoobarExports
  LIBRARY DESTINATION ${my_install_destination})
install(EXPORT FoobarExports DESTINATION ${my_install_destination})
# Create the FoobarExports.cmake for the local build tree
export(EXPORT FoobarExports) # the problematic command

# Setup FoobarConfig.cmake etc
# FoobarConfig.cmake includes FoobarExports.cmake
# ...

# Force find_package to FOOBAR_DIR
option(BUILD_EXAMPLES "Build examples" ON)
if(BUILD_EXAMPLES)
  set(FOOBAR_DIR "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}")
  add_subdirectory(examples)
endif()

### examples/CMakeLists.txt ###
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(FoobarExamples)
# Uses FOOBAR_DIR set above
find_package(Foobar NO_MODULE REQUIRED)

add_executable(my_exe ${some_sources})
# Use X from Foobar
target_link_library(my_exe X)
```

The problem is that `export(EXPORT FoobarExports)` will only create the `FoobarExports.cmake` file at the end of generation time to make sure it has the complete `FoobarExports` export set.

So this will fail:

```
cmake . -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=ON
# Error: FoobarExports.cmake not found
```

What works, however, is:

```
cmake .
cmake . -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=ON # rerun cmake with changed cache variable
```

How can I either force the `FoobarExports.cmake` file to be written at the time of the call to `export` or force CMake to run twice, if the file has not been created yet?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to find anything if you're building your project as a subproject. Just check
the target exists and if not, try to find it. Something like that:

```
### examples/CMakeLists.txt ###
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(FoobarExamples)

if(NOT TARGET X)
  find_package(Foobar CONFIG REQUIRED)
endif()

# Use X from Foobar
target_link_library(my_exe X)
```

Comment: I see where you are coming from. This has two side problems: it makes the CMakeLists.txt unnecessarily messy and I cannot just use `X` because I export targets with a namespace. And then the code would become even messier.

Comment: ALIAS targets are designed to solve that problem (since CMake 2.8.12). http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#alias-targets

Comment: `it makes the CMakeLists.txt unnecessarily messy` IMHO one `if` command is not messy

Comment: @steveire I completely forgot about `ALIAS` targets. Thanks.